# Seeing different font sizes in different lists with the same spec

Tags: xetex, fontsize, deedy-resume

I made my resume with a customized version of the two column [Deedy-Resume](https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume) template. I am seeing slightly different font sizes and font spacing in two different `tightemize` lists. `tightemize` is a more compact version of the unordered list in the template.

I have uploaded a resume with boilerplate text to illustrate my problem [here](https://github.com/pratnala/resume-test). Under the `Work Experience` section in the pdf, you can see the bullet points in the top section are spaced out more and have a bigger font size. Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a link to an external file.

Answer (score 1):

Your section commands are forcing centering and font changes over the whole document, which is why  you keep needing to re-apply `\justfying` (if you *ever* find yourself needing that you should instead fix whatever bug caused loss of justification.

for example

```
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{
\centering{
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/dubai/, Mapping = tex-text]{Dubai-Regular.ttf}\selectfont #1
\fontspec[Path = fonts/dubai/, Mapping = tex-text]{Dubai-Regular.ttf}\selectfont #2
} \\[5pt]
\centering{
\color{headings}
\fontspec[Path = fonts/dubai/, Mapping = tex-text]{Dubai-Medium.ttf}
\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont #3}
\vspace{3pt}
}
```

applies  `\centering` (twice!) to the entire document after the command is used. You sould use `\centering` inside a group.

```
\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont #3}
```

should be

```
\fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont #3\par}%
```

so the paragraph ends within the group so uses a line spacing suitable for the font size.

Similarly

```
newcommand{\runsubsection}[1]{
\color{subheadings}\fontspec[Path = fonts/sanfrancisco/, Mapping = tex-text]{SFProText-Medium.ttf}\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\selectfont\bfseries\uppercase {#1} \normalfont}
```

should use a group to contain the font and size to the heading.

Comment: I am still seeing the first `tightemize` group having different line spacing and font size compared to the rest. Why is that happening?

Comment: @pratnala I made an exception and followed the external link as you are new but you should make an example here. but I just showed two examples here, you need similar fixes to almost every definition in your file.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Just wanted to know what you meant by `should be within a group`. I didn't get that.

Comment: @pratnala if you have `\bfseries{ABC}...` the rest of the document is bold not just ABC. you need `{\bfseries ABC} ...` so the font change ends at the end of the group `}`